# Why is my PhaseListener not recognized as implementation of javax.faces.event.PhaseListener?

Tags: java, jsf, tomcat, phaselistener

I have a JSF-Application with a custom PhaseListener that works fine on Tomcat 6.0.24.
Server startup looks like:

```
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/6.0.24
26.01.2012 09:54:21 com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener contextInitialized
INFO: Initializing Mojarra (1.2_13-b01-FCS) for context '/myapp'
```

Deploying the same application on a fresh Tomcat 6.0.35 installation, it shows:

```
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/6.0.35
...
26.01.2012 10:10:26 com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener contextInitialized
INFO: Initializing Mojarra (1.2_13-b01-FCS) for context '/myapp'
26.01.2012 10:10:26 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SCHWERWIEGEND: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener
com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: CONFIGURATION FAILED! 
  Source Document: jndi:/localhost/zav-gui/WEB-INF/faces-config.xml
  Cause: Class 'mypackage.CustomPhaseListener' is not an instance of 'interface javax.faces.event.PhaseListener'
```

Some Google hits point to wrong JSF version number, but these are obviously the same. But what else could cause this? Thanks for any help.

**UPDATE**
The error happens on a clean 6.0.24 installation also. Here is the content of `TOMCAT_INST\lib`:

[image]

My Application has this JSF related files in WEB-INF\lib:

[image]

Comment: Out of interest was your 6.0.24 tomcat also a fresh installation?

Comment: Can it be a classloaders related issue?  Maybe you have 2 different jars that contain PhaseListener. Checked you war?

Comment: That might be a class loading problem, i.e. you might get a different version of `javax.faces.event.PhaseListener` than `mypackage.CustomPhaseListener` implements due to different classloaders being used. Did you enable application isolation in your 6.0.24 Tomcat and in the 6.0.35 version as well?

Comment: @Kevin - no, and encouraged by your question I setup a clean 6.0.24... and what should I say... the same problem comes up! Will update the question :)

Comment: @Thomas Please see my updates regarding the libs. How do I enable application isolation?

Comment: Have you compared the various tomcat config files of your working version, and the two fresh versions. It's possible there is something that has been configured in your working version you've forgotten about.

Comment: I'm not sure how that would be done with plain Tomcat, maybe it's even not an issue here. We're using JBoss which has an embedded Tomcat and there's a config file where isolation is enabled. For classloading in plain Tomcat, refer to the documentation: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/class-loader-howto.html